An algorithm to arrange max number of copies of a polygon around and touching another polygon
A related post: To place copies of a planar convex region such that number of 'contacts' among them is maximized
Basic question: Given two convex polygonal regions P and Q, to arrange the max possible number of copies of Q around a single P unit with all the Q's touching the central P with no two regions overlapping. Can an algorithm be found to solve any P and Q? The case of P and Q being the same could be interesting in itself.
Remarks: If one can think of the rotating calipers method as a polygon rolling on its edge along a plane, the present question seems like two gear wheels P and Q rotating while staying in contact.
A couple of variants:

For a fixed convex P (say, a square) and a number n, to construct a convex Q with least number of sides such that n (but no more) copies of Q can be put around a central P and touching it. Will an equilateral triangle of suitable side suffice for any P and n?

Given a number n (say 11), to find a convex P such that n (and no more) copies of P can be arranged around a central P and touching it. Guess: a suitable isosceles triangle might work for any n.


Note: The question has a  natural analog in 3D. Further possibilities include insisting that the contacts between polygons be at exactly one point.

Shouldn't the first question be decidable by Tarski-Seidenberg? For given $n, P, Q$, express the configuration by a bunch of real parameters (subject to some equations for the rotations), and the touching and non-overlapping by more equations and inequalities. Then the existence of a solution is decidable. Of course, this is not going to produce a practical algorithm.

(sorry, of course this only gives an algorithm that decides whether $n$ copies of $Q$ fit around $P$ for given $n$, but since one can get an a priori upper bound from considering diameters and areas, one just needs to run it finitely many times to find the maximum $n$)

Thanks. Is checking whether an arrangement can be made for each n until the limit is reached an optimal algorithmic approach? Alternatively, can one find the max number of Q units that can touch each edge of P (each edge is a line segment) and then patch the answers of segments together   (complications might arise from this patching)?

No, none of this is optimal, everything I wrote just considers the abstract question of whether such an algorithm exists.

See my kissing-number comment below.


"the max possible number of copies of Q around a single P unit with all the Q's touching the central P."

Perhaps the problem is not stated precisely? This example seems to
show that there might be no max---an infinite number of copies of $Q$ all
surrounding and touching $P$ is possible.


Thank you. I had meant "no two of the regions overlap". Made an edit in the question.

Ah, I see. You are asking a variant of The kissing number of a square, cube, hypercube?. Generalized to arbitrary convex $P$ and $Q$. "Kissing number" is the key search phrase.

Thanks for the pointer to this question - and its beautiful answer
